# How to read data from barcode reader by using C++ program?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am completely new to the world of network programming. I have some basic knowledge in C++. I have a barcode reader. I have to develop a program which will read the codes send by the barcode reader. I want to get a direction as the number of option available on internet is confusing.

Regards

Comment: Start with reading your device' manual/specs, eg. if sockets are the right approach at all.

Comment: Your question is way too broad. You should start doing your research and ask questions on specific programming issue you may encounter during your development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the abstraction of your question my help will only go to a certain limit.

On a recent job, where I had to use a barcode scanner integrated with a Java desktop application, the following approach was taken:

- Identification of the serial port where the barcode was attached;
- In the Java application, open and establish a connection to that serial port;
- Attach an event listener to the recently created serial port connection;
- Listen for new events and process them.

Now its up to you to make this happen in C++.